# About Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg complementing boundary condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let's consider the following Poisson equation with Neumann boundary condition

\begin{align*}
-\Delta u &= f \quad \text{in } \Omega \\
\partial_n u&=0 \quad \text{on } \partial \Omega,
\end{align*}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is bounded domain with smooth boundary.
It is obvious that
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega f \, dx =0
\end{align*}
to ensure existence of solutions to the Poisson equation.

Recently, I have read famous paper "Estimates near the boundary for solutions of elliptic partial differential equations satisfying general boundary conditions I,II" (Comm. Pure Appl. Math., 1959,1964) written by Agmon,Douglis, and Nirenberg. In this paper, they introduced the complementing boundary condition which is very algebraic. I checked that the Poisson equation with Neumann boundary condition satisfies the complementing boundary condition.

The weird thing here is that it seems to satisfy the complementing boundary condition regardless of values $\int f$. I think I may have missed something in Agmon's argument. I would appreciate it if you could provide me with an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Note the proper use of `\text{}` in MathJax. And also I changed $\displaystyle \int f dx$ to $\displaystyle \int f\, dx. \qquad$

Comment: Yes, the complementing condition is independent of any conditions of f. But nowhere is it claimed that the complementing condition guarantees existence.